# SQL Transactions : Sign "in" without matching "out"

Tags: mysql, matching

bah, complicated questions to ask database.

I have a series of sign in and sign out events over a day for a range of users. 
I want to track all those who forget to sign out: i.e. the last transaction on a given date was "IN". I want to summarise who these people were:

```
personid  datetime            activity
ABC1      2015-09-01 08:00:00 IN
DEF2      2015-09-01 09:00:00 IN
ABC1      2015-09-01 12:00:00 OUT
ABC1      2015-09-01 13:04:00 IN
GHI3      2015-09-01 08:30:00 IN
GHI3      2015-09-01 15:50:00 OUT
ABC1      2015-09-01 14:00:00 OUT
ABC1      2015-09-01 14:20:00 IN
GHI3      2015-09-03 16:01:00 IN
ABC1      2015-09-03 16:00:00 OUT
```

So in this case, I want a list:

```
DEF2 didn't sign out 
GHI3 didn't sign out second time
```

Note, as shown, there could be multiple sign-in/sign-outs in a given day.

Comment: t-sql on VistaDB by the way, so top() not limit

Comment: you can count IN's and OUT's of each user. If the subtraction of those values are different from zero, then someones forget to sign out :)

Comment: never underestimate user's ability to press wrong buttons: I need to accurately reflect the fact that the *last* item in the list (by time) was an IN, not an OUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the last activity ( by the date ) and if it is IN then, there is not OUT after this

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT personid, 
                max(datetime),
                activity FROM table GROUP BY personid) t1
WHERE t1.activity = 'OUT'
```